# How to prevent auto mounting of encrypted APFS volumes by diskarbitrationd

Tags: encryption, apfs

running 10.14.5 on a 2019 iMac.

diskarbitrationd is responsible for noticing the appearance of new block devices and mounting them. this kind of auto mounting can be prevented by configuring /etc/fstab with lines such as the following:

LABEL=VolumeName   none   apfs   rw,noauto

This works for all types of filesystems (including unencrypted APFS) except encrypted APFS. On restart, diskarbitrationd attempts to mount the volume and a popup appears with an authentication dialog (one for each encrypted volume) requesting the encryption passphrase. Does anyone know how to stop diskarbitrationd from automatically mounting encrypted APFS volumes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I too would love to know the answer to this. [This other thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310574/how-to-prevent-auto-mounting-of-a-volume-in-macos-high-sierra) has some discussion about it but seems to conclude that adding entries to fstab using labels or UUIDs doesn't work with APFS.