# Preventing Volume Unlock Prompt

Tags: macos, catalina, encryption, apfs, unlock

I have an encrypted APFS volume that I do not wish to be unlocked automatically, however, every time a user logs in on my system they are prompted to enter a passphrase for the volume, every single time.

What I want to know is, is there a way to prevent macOS from trying to unlock specific APFS volumes when a user logs in, or even better, to only do-so if a password is found in that user's keychain (so I can have it auto-mount for *some* users but be ignored for others)?

I've already tried adding the volume to `/etc/fstab` with the `noauto` option, but while all other settings are respected when the volume is mounted, this one is ignored, presumably because unlocking of APFS volumes occurs before the volume is mounted.

Comment: Do you have FileVault enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible prevent the unlock prompt by changing the role of the encrypted volume!

1. Get the device identifier (and the UUID which is required later) of the encrypted volume:

   ```
   diskutil ap list
   ```
2. Change the volume role:

   ```
   diskutil ap changeVolumeRole diskXsY D
   ```

   APFS can use flags to determine a special role of a volume: S=System volume/B=Preboot etc. A simple encrypted volume (no boot/system volume group) usually has no specific role. **For unknown reason the D (=Data) role prevents the unlock prompt and the volume won't be mounted automatically**.

To mount and unlock the volume for a user (here: the user currently logged in) create a launch agent:

3. Create a launch agent:

   ```
   nano ~/Library/LaunchAgents/usr.automount.plist
   ```

   and add the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>Disabled</key>
       <false/>
       <key>Label</key>
       <string>usr.automount</string>
       <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
           <string>/usr/sbin/diskutil</string>
           <string>ap</string>
           <string>unlock</string>
           <string><UUID_of_encrypted_APFS_volume></string>
           <string>-passphrase</string>
           <string><password></string>
       </array>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

   Example with the UUID *4E253DC9-5B87-49CB-96F3-DE4737C16464* and the password *test*:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
       <key>Disabled</key>
       <false/>
       <key>Label</key>
       <string>usr.automount</string>
       <key>ProgramArguments</key>
       <array>
           <string>/usr/sbin/diskutil</string>
           <string>ap</string>
           <string>unlock</string>
           <string>4E253DC9-5B87-49CB-96F3-DE4737C16464</string>
           <string>-passphrase</string>
           <string>test</string>
       </array>
       <key>RunAtLoad</key>
       <true/>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```

   Save the file in nano
4. Load the launch agent:

   ```
   launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/usr.automount.plist
   ```

---

This won't unload and lock the encrypted volume if you log out as user1 (unlock enabled) and log in as user2 (unlock disabled) without reboot!

---

**Checking your other questions, I realized that you might have specific mount points for encrypted volumes (e.g. mounted to user folders/subfolders). The simple approach in the launch agent won't work then.**

Comment: What does the role do, and what is the meaning of `D`? The `diskutil` man page doesn't explain roles, and doesn't even know about `D` (at least not in Mojave)?

Comment: what is the difference between this answer and the solution proposed above? You just expanded what @GYBE linked there..

Comment: @MPA I started to (test and) write this answer a while before GYBE modified the completely wrong first version of his answer.

Comment: @klanomath well, the other one was 2h before. To me this is a duplicate

Comment: This answer solved it! I'm thinking the `D` role must be used by the new "data" volume in Catalina which is mounted over the read-only system volume. Why it avoids the unlock prompt I'm not sure, but I'm happy for that to be the case!

Don't worry about the mounting in my case, I believe if I've set an fstab entry it should still be used on unlock, I can also maybe use a script to do auto-unmount.

Answer (score 1):

If it asks for multiple passwords when a user logs in, probably you did not enable that user in FileVault.

You can do that from the System Preferences:

- On the Mac computer, open System Preferences > Security & Privacy.
- Click the FileVault tab, and if necessary, unlock the padlock.
- Click the Enable Users button and an account list pops up.
- Click Enable Users to add and enter the password of that user.

or from the command line:

- on the Mac computer, open the Terminal application.
- Run the following command: `sudo fdesetup add -usertoadd user1` and if prompted, enter the `sudo` password.
- When prompted, enter the primary FileVault-authorized user name —
  this is the user who you specified to manage FileVault 2 (in Assign an Active Directory user who is authorized to manage an encrypted disk).
- When prompted, enter the password for the primary
  FileVault-authorized user.
- When prompted, enter the password for the new user who you specified
  on the command line (user1 in this example).

**Regarding your other question, to prevent Volume unlock Prompt**, I think you can combine some things since on MacOS there is not a native utility to do what you asked (like `libpam-mount` for deb systems). More specifically:

1. You can disable an APFS volume to automount. You can follow the second answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310574/how-to-prevent-auto-mounting-of-a-volume-in-macos-high-sierra).
2. You can write a script to mount a volume, instead of typing the command line command every time you need it. You can read more about this [here](https://appademic.tech/automatically-unlock-apfs-volume-with-applescript/).
3. You can launch the script at startup. You could use `launchd`. You can check some approaches in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/229773/run-command-on-startup-login-mac-os-x).
4. Obviously, you'd want to launch the script on a user basis. [Here](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/script-management-with-launchd-apdc6c1077b-5d5d-4d35-9c19-60f2397b2369/mac), you can read the official documentation for it. Additionally, in the thread linked at *point 3* there are some mentions about launching a start-up script on a user basis.

I hope it is useful now in some sort of way, and sorry for misinterpreting the question.

Comment: If I read the question correctly, the OP wants to prevent the mounting of the encrypted partition by default, so authorizing the user for FV probably won't help.

Comment: This is an answer to a completely different question...

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood the question. I have added a more appropriate answer now.