# Is there a way to make an iMac's internal drive disappear completely WITHOUT removing it?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, external-disk

I want to make it so that it can't be seen or written to while booted from an external drive.

For some background, I use a cross-platform dev environment that can target Linux and want to install the recommended Linux distro for testing. Every time I've tried before, it wrote a boot loader to the internal drive that must be messed up because my Bootcamped Win 10 won't boot afterwards. If it matters the req'd distro is Linux Mint Cinnamon Edition.

Comment: You mean just so it doesn't auto-mount? `fstab` can do that - rather outdated but still effective way to do that - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205866/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin The system of an arbitrary external boot drive won't contain a working fstab...

Comment: It won't, but we don't actually know what the OP has or needs. I'm just positing a possibility. if you know a global structure to do this [& I'm very aware you know 10x more than I do on this type of topic] go for it :)

Comment: @Tetsujin Access to the macOS sources & build system of Apple system engineers is required to smuggle in a fstab file with the UUIDs of the various volumes of Bryan's iMac ;)

Comment: @klanomath :-))

Comment: I trying to install another OS to the external HD without it putting a boot loader on the internal drive since "Option-booting" makes it unnecessary. All the advice I've found says to physically disconnect the internal drive but I'm disabled and can't do that myself and the only local shop willing to open and repair my iMac closed last month.

Comment: You don’t need to put a boot loader on the internal drive.  You just have to remove the bootable portion - or even easier, wipe it clean.  But it wont make it invisible because if it’s connected, it can be seen and mounted.  Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I use a cross-platform dev environment that can target Linux and want to install the recommended Linux distro for testing. Every time I've tried before, it wrote a boot loader to the internal drive that must be messed up because my Bootcamped Win 10 won't boot afterwards. If it matters the req'd distro is Linux Mint Cinnamon Edition.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have two questions/issues:

1) A Linux system has "boot jacked" your boot manager/boot loader, messing up Windows.

2) Hiding above system from macOS.

You could give rEFInd a try to fix/manage your boot issues.  It should solve 1 but not 2 per se.

There may be a solution for 2 here:
[How to prevent auto mounting of a volume in macOS High Sierra?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/310574/249402)

Comment: How did you come to any of those conclusions based on what was posted?

Comment: @Allan OP wrote in a comment, "I use a cross-platform dev environment that can target Linux and want to install the recommended Linux distro for testing. Every time I've tried before, it wrote a boot loader to the internal drive that must be messed up because my Bootcamped Win 10 won't boot afterwards. If it matters the req'd distro is Linux Mint Cinnamon Edition."

Comment: that should be in the question - I didn't see it under the rolled up comments - and it completely changes the context of the OPs original post.  Do you have edit privilege yet?  If so, edit it and get the credit for the fix as well.

Comment: @Allan Agreed.  I am unable and unfamiliar with editing an original question.  It should be suggested to OP, I assume.  (And, I also don't like the rolling up of comments.)

Comment: There's an [edit] button at the bottom of each question, if you've got the privilege (points).  The OP *should* put it in, but many put things in comments (sigh).  You get more more privileges when you edit X number of posts, etc.  I don't need them so I was giving first crack at it to you.

Comment: I can only suggest an edit, which I have done.

Comment: Cool..after so many of those, you'll be able to bypass the edit queue and make it instant.  And I just approved it. ;-)

Comment: @Allan Found a thread with possible solutions. I added a link.  Eager to try it myself....